# Use node from homebrew

Tags: node.js, terminal, homebrew

Running `node -v` in the terminal returns **0.12.2**, while running `brew info node` to check homebrew's version of node, it returns **6.7.0**

**How can I work using homebrew's node?** (6.7.0 instead of 0.12.2)

I've tried reinstalling everything, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two options...

Either specify the full path to where `hombrew` installed `node` each and every time you use it:

```
/usr/local/bin/node -v
```

Or, change your `PATH` in your login profile to put `/usr/local/bin` ahead of everything else:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I've tried that, but running `node -v` still returns **0.12.2**. If its pointing to the homebrew folder, shouldn't it return the same version I see when I run `brew info node`?

Comment: If you exported the PATH in your login profile, it will only execute next time you log in. To set it in your current session (without logging in afresh), just type the command in Terminal `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`. Then try `node -v` again.

Comment: Nope. Tried it now, but its not changing the return of `node -v` :/

Comment: Try `/usr/local/bin/node -v`

Comment: It returns 0.12.2 as well

Comment: Try `brew rm node --force; brew install node` and check any warnings about not linking

Comment: Thanks. I found an error with the `brew link`. Forcing the overwrite of the link solved the problem

Comment: I am going to bed now! If that didn't work, try `brew doctor` and let it tell you what is wrong with your setup. And if that doesn't work, try running `type node` to see if it is aliased or something mad, other than `/usr/local/bin/node`. Finally, pretend your Mac is Windows and try rebooting it.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use homebrew, use nvm. https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Not only is it easier to install and use, it also allows you to have multiple versions of node/npm installed and switch between them effortlessly (e.g. `nvm install v6.7.0` and `nvm use v6.7.0`)